# How create composite foreign key to table with composite primary key

Tags: entity-framework-6, foreign-keys, code-first

I have two tables with composite primary keys:

```cs
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string ID1 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ID2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public string DocID1 { get; set; }
    public int DocID2 { get; set; }
```

}

```cs
public class EventDocument
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string ID1 { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ID2 { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create a composite foreign key on `Event` table to `EventDocument` table

I've tried to create FK like this

class Event:

```cs
[ForeignKey("DocID1")]
[Column(Order = 0)]
public string DocID1 { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("DocID2")]
[Column(Order = 1)]
public string DocID2 { get; set; }
```

But I get an error:

> The property 'DocID1' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type."}

I don't understand anymore what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Composite foreign key requires [`ForeignKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to be applied on the navigation property specifying the comma separated list of the foreign key property names:

> If you add the **ForeignKey** attribute to a foreign key property, you should specify the name of the associated navigation property. If you add the **ForeignKey** attribute to a navigation property, you should specify the name of the associated foreign key(s). If a navigation property has multiple foreign keys, use comma to separate the list of foreign key names.

Since you have no navigation property in the `Event` class, you should apply it on the corresponding navigation property in the `EventDocument` class:

```cs
[ForeignKey("DocID1, DocID2")]
public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
```

and the issue should be resolved.

But I personally find setting up relationships with Fluent API to be much easier to understand and less error prone. For instance, the same can be achieved by the following fluent configuration:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<EventDocument>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Events)
    .WithRequired() // or .WithOptional()
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.DocID1, e.DocID2 });
```

Same btw for the composite PKs (instead of all these `Key` / `Column(Order = ...)` attributes):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.ID1, e.ID2 });

modelBuilder.Entity<EventDocument>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.ID1, e.ID2 });
```

Comment: What a clear answer!!! Going to try and accept :) And what do You mean by writing EventA: "public virtual ICollection<EventA> Events { get; set; }"

Comment: First I've tryed to 1 var. I got an error: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'DocID1' on type 'xxx.Event' is not valid. The navigation property 'DocID1, DocID2' was not found on the dependent type 'xxx.Event'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name. Goint to try Fluent API

Comment: Staying with Fluen API, realyy much easier to understand an NO MORE ERRORS. Thank You

Comment: In my EF test project I already had class called `Event`, so I had to rename your to `EventA`, and then simply forgot to correct it after copy/pasting, sorry about that.

Comment: Than You one more time! Helped too much!!

Comment: This not gonna work. In EF you can't map 2 FK relationships to one and the same collection navigation property. Basically you need another collection property, something like `public virtual ICollection<Event> Events2 { get; set; }` in the class and  `modelBuilder.Entity<EventDocument>().HasMany(e => e.Events2) .WithOptional() .HasForeignKey(f => new { f.Doc2ID1, f.Doc2ID2});` in the configuration.