# Foreign key to two fields in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a table, like:

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
    Id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Uid VARCHAR,
    Version INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
    ...
);

' Uid is a GUID
```

The whole idea is to version the items. If user wants to edit non-draft item, he only may do so with its newest version and in such case object is deep-cloned and user works on its clone with incremented version.

There is a way to select only newest items, like:

```
SELECT i.* FROM Item AS i
LEFT JOIN Item AS i1 ON i1.Version > i.Version AND i1.Uid = i.Uid
WHERE i1.Id IS NULL
```

This would be hard to achieve in EF (and even if I did that it still would be more time-complex than other solutions), so I'm planning to create a table with only newest versions of items, like:

```
CREATE TABLE NewestItems (
    Uid VARCHAR NOT NULL
    Version INTEGER NOT NULL );
```

It's quite simple to maintain track of newest versions, because there is only one occasion, when it changes - when user commits a draft. However, I'd like to make contract in the database to make sure, that NewestItems points to actual Items (I'll make sure, that these are the newest ones).

In SQL I'd create a key from pair: Uid and Version and then create foreign key in NewestItems. But I'm designing the database code first and I have no idea, how can I do that.

So the question: how to define (code first) a key consisting of pair of two fields and then foreign key to this key?

Moreover: is there a way do create navigation property from Item to NewestItem (or the other way around), such that I can easily pick newest Items?

Comment: Do you mean a [composite foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556676/how-create-composite-foreign-key-to-table-with-composite-primary-key)?

Comment: Sounds promissing, the only problem is that I'm not referring to primary key, but to couple of fields, which can be an index at best...